# iOS App Replacement instead of updating

Tags: ios, xcode, version, updates

Please consider the following scenario:

I have an application installed in my iOS device which is of **version 1.0**. Now I have made changes to the application and kept the **app identifier** same as the **version 1.0** application. The version of the changed application is **version 1.1**. Is it possible for iOS app to replace the previous app completely? and not update.

Are there any build settings in Xcode?

Thanks,
Ankit Tanna

Comment: What's the difference between the app being replaced and it being updated? What is your goal?

Comment: App being replaced means its a totally a fresh installation. and App being upgraded means it keeps existing downloaded content of the older build. My goal is to replace the previous app installed by the user by my new app with changes. I dont want the user to manually uninstall and then install the new app.

Comment: I hope you got what I'm trying.

Comment: You have two choices. 1) Create a new app with a new app id. 2) Do a normal update but have your updated app purge any existing data the first time it is run.

Comment: Okay Maddy, 1st one is what I cannot do. 2nd one: how can we purge the data in the first run?

Comment: There are plenty of existing questions covering how to do stuff only the first time an app is run. Do some searching for that. As for purging, it depends on what and where the data is stored. Use `NSFileManager` to enumerate and delete any existing files you don't want anymore.

Comment: When you update an app from AppStore, all of its old bundle resources gets removed anyway and only the files stored in Sandbox remains. If you want to completely remove the files from Sandbox as well, you can write the code in your new updated app.

Comment: @Puneet yes puneet, this is exactly what I want to do? is there a way to do that?

Comment: aS @rmaddy said , you need to learn to use NSFileManager. You have methods ijn AppDelegate that gets called when you run the app on first time. Play with NSFileManager in these methods to delete the files in sandbox. Try on these lines and if you stuck somewhere, I am sure people in SO will help.

Comment: Thanks. Right point to kick off :)